# Section not defined In Index.cshtml in asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, alert

I define the section in Index. cshtml but when I run the application then generate an error section is not defined 
I create the same another project, then define the simple method in Index. cshtml then run my application but my current project popup not be displayed??

another project
_layout.cshtml

```
<div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("simpelmessage")
        <footer>
            <p>WebApi Crud Oeperation using Entity Framework In Mvc</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@section simpelmessage{
   <h1>simple message</h1>
}
```

that is work in another project

but my current working project my popup should not be displayed??
I m performing crud operation using api

_layout.cshtml

```
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        @RenderSection("alertpopup")
        <footer>
            <p>WebApi Crud Oeperation using Entity Framework In Mvc</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@section alertpopup
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var successmessage = '@ViewBag.message'  
            if (successmessage != '') 
            {
                alertify.success(successmessage);
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<studentmvcmodel> stdlist;
            HttpResponseMessage response = globalvariable.webapiclient.GetAsync("studlogins").Result;
            stdlist = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<studentmvcmodel>>().Result;
            ViewBag.message = "record is inserted";
            return View(stdlist);
        }

        public ActionResult create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult create(studentmvcmodel stud)
        {
            var username = stud.username;
            var passs = stud.password;
            if (username != null && passs != null)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = globalvariable.webapiclient.PostAsJsonAsync("studlogins", stud).Result;
                ViewBag.message = "data inserted successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.message = "please all the data fillup carefully";
                return View("create");
            }
        }
```

My record should be created, but I want to popup message when submits the record?? but give the error section is not defined?? 
What I am trying I went to when I press the submit button, then a popup should be displayed but popup not display?

I hope my question is understood?

I m going to the browser and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then show the popup function.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js" type="text/javascript">        


        $(function popup()
        {
            var successmessage = 'record is inserted';
            if (successmessage != '')
            {
                //alertify.success(successmessage);
                alert('record is inserted');
            }
        });
        popup();
      </script>
```

Comment: @if (IsSectionDefined("alertpopup"))
    {
    @RenderSection("alertpopup", required: true);
    }. Use this line instead of just rendering the section.

Comment: What do you set `Layout` property in `Index.cshtml`?

Comment: @MahdiAsgari ```@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}``` I add the masterpage in _layout.cshtml not work??

Comment: @HameedSyed I set your code as per your suggestion but popup does not display when  I press the submit button

Comment: You mean: you have `section is not defined` error when your page is loading?

Comment: @MahdiAsgari when I press start btn and then click create new then give an error ```Additional information: Section not defined: "alertpopup".``` I m trying to solve this problem last 1 days but issue not solved plz help

Comment: After you call your `Create` action you return RedirectToAction("Index") or View("create")?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid **section is not defined** error you need to call RenderSection as below.

```
  @RenderSection("alertpopup", false)
```

And to make the pop up work, you have defined your javascript function but you are not calling you function anywhere. you can do this instead.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
      function popup () {
        var successmessage = '@ViewBag.message'  
        if (successmessage != '') 
        {
            alertify.success(successmessage);
        }
    }
  popup();
  </script>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204979/discussion-on-answer-by-rajesh-g-section-not-defined-in-index-cshtml-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 0):

If you return View("create"), so you should render your section in `Create.cshtml` Or define this @RenderSection("alertpopup", false)  in your Layout

Answer (score 0):

Rendering sections take two parameters; a string and a boolean as such:

`@RenderSection(string name, bool required)`

The `name` parameter is name of the section to render and `required` indicates that the section must always be rendered. If the section may not be rendered in some views or sometime, you should set required to false like below.

`@RenderSection("alertpopup", false)`

I'm also not sure when you want your popup to display because it is not called in your code. If for whatever reason you'll want it to be called when your documents loads, you should change your code to this

```
@section alertpopup
{
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/AlertifyJS/1.13.1/alertify.min.js" type="text/javascript">
        $(doucument).ready(function () {
            var successmessage = '@ViewBag.message'  
            if (successmessage != '') 
            {
                alertify.success(successmessage);
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: ```<script>alert('@ViewBag.message')</script>``` this is work but your jquery code is not work sill i m trying